# Facebook Connect - Login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login, smf

I want to intergrate facebook login with my SMF ( Simple Machines ) Forum PHP based. Now they modules that was written is for SMF is 2 years old and not working with current version in addition all download links are broken so i cant find any help from that.

I tried facebook developers website but there is so much random info very unorganized. Any way if anyone had done this before ( intergrated FBC login with their wbesite or forum ) can you share some HOW TO information or any helpfull resources / articles on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

what's your SMF version? if your version is 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4 you can download the modules in

```
http://custom.simplemachines.org/mods/index.php?mod=2322
```

and you can see here how to setup in facebook developer site.

```
http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=365503.0
```